# Can a team mate give lifting/climbing support?

Tags: rules, football

Can a team mate give lifting/climbing support so that a player can reach the height where goalie or any opponent cannot reach? Is climbing on the goal post allowed?

Comment: Lifting support probably isn't disallowed but I don't see it as very practical. The ball is moving too fast for two players to construct a "ladder". And it would be hard for a ball fired at this height to go into the net.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is classed as unsporting behaviour. The player doing the lifting, or the player doing the climbing is cautioned for unsporting behaviour, and the opponents are awarded an indirect free kick from where the lift/climb occurred.

Although this is not explicitly mentioned in the Laws of the Game, it is known to be unsporting behaviour through tradition.

Each year the United States Soccer Federation releases an [Advice To Referees](http://www.vadcsoccerref.com/home/370581.html) document. This documents fills in the gaps of "tradition" vs what is actually codified in the FIFA Laws of the Game. In the 2014 edition, on pages 50-51:

> Referees are urged to review the list of examples of
>   unsporting behavior to be found in
>   the Interpretation of the Laws of the Game and Guidelines for Referees as well as in
>   U.S. Soccer training materials for newer referees. Other examples include:
>
> ...
>
> - Uses an artificial aid to unfairly assist play – for example, leaning on the
>     shoulders of a teammate to increase height, using an article of clothing to avoid
>     direct contact with the ball, removing the corner flag on a corner kick, hanging on
>     the crossbar.

Comment: Not much unsporting though.

Comment: It doesn't really give you a huge advantage, but it's playing the game in a way that it's not intended to be played. The caution for unsporting behaviour would be written up as "acts in a manner which shows a lack of respect for the game" - p. 123 of the 2014/15 Laws of the Game (http://www.fifa.com/aboutfifa/footballdevelopment/technicalsupport/refereeing/laws-of-the-game/index.html